# C++ vectors, sorting and custom class operators

Tags: c++, class, operators, assignment-operator, comparison-operators

I am puzzled because I cannot figure where my bug/problem is.
I have a class Instruction, which uses two custom operators, one assignment and one comparison operator.
Previously I only used the comparison operator in order to use std::sort to sort Instructions based on one of their members, an std::string name.
However, since I started re-factoring the entire project, I changed some members to constant. This lead me to having to use an initialization list for those constants.
This in turn, lead me to have to create an assignment operator, because those instructions are being copied when pushed back in vectors.
This is where everything goes wrong.
I include my Class declaration and Constructor and Operators.

instruction.hpp

```
class Instruction 
{
  private:  
    unsigned int param_size;
    const float max_angle, min_angle;
    bool micro_mutated;
  protected:
    const std::string body_part;
    std::vector<Parameter <float> > parameters;
  public:
    Instruction(std::string name, float max, float min);
    Instruction operator=(const Instruction& I);
    bool operator<(const Instruction& I) const;
    //there are a few more functions but are completely irrelevant
}
```

instruction.cpp:

```
Instruction::Instruction(std::string name,float max, float min) :
body_part (name), max_angle(max), min_angle(min)
{}

Instruction Instruction::operator=(const Instruction& I)
{
  (*this) = I;
  return (*this);
}

bool Instruction::operator<(const Instruction& I) const
{
  return body_part < I.body_part;
}
```

The only reason why I created an assignment operator (which to be honest I've never done before) was because when I was trying to push_back Instructions, compiler complained about not being able to instantiate "from here" Instructions and I thought it had to do with the constant members. Without the members being constant, everything worked fine, even the sorting.
Now the weird part. If I remove the std::sort, the above code works, but not all the time. Some times it crashed after a while, some times it won't crash. But the moment I include the sorting, it crashes straight away.
Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget the rule of threes: if you have one of a copy construct, copy assignment operator, and destructor, then you should have *all* of them.

However, your copy assignment operator is effectively an infinite loop; it calls itself. Operator= will be used whenever you have anything of the form: `Instruction &=Instruction&`. Which is exactly what `(*this) = I` is.

My question is this: why are those things constant? Having members be constant effectively means that you *cannot* copy the object (unless you use a const-cast) with copy assignment. You can copy construct them, but that's about it.

Is there some reason for those members to be constant? And if so, then you shouldn't be copying these objects by assignment. The two are mutually exclusive.

If you need a member to be effectively constant, unchangable by outside activity (but not *language*-const which prevents copying), then this should be done with proper accessor methods. Provide users of the class with ways to get these values, but not ways to set them.

Comment: Those members are accessible from other classes, and I want to be sure that their values will not be changed.
However, I do want their values to be copyable.
Where is the infinite loop, I'm confused

Comment: @Alex: Then those other classes should use accessors to get at those values rather than getting them directly. The only class that should be directly touching the member variables of a class is the class _itself_.

Comment: So, I should just not have them constants, use getters for other classes, and remove the assignment operator ?

Comment: Nicol is absolutely right, `(*this) = I;` calls the assignment operator (itself) producing infinite recursion.  You can't write an assignment operator with `const` member variables, and you can't `sort` without an assignment operator.  Either keep pointers in your vector (so only pointers are assigned and not objects), or make the member variables private and non-const, and provide protected inline accessor functions which return them by const reference.

Comment: Ok, now I see where the problem is.
Thank you very much !